# Android Circle Seekbar with NO Maximum

Tags: android, geometry, seekbar

I would like a circular seekbar that has no maximum.  Meaning you can keep going around and around the circle and always incrementing the number.  Actually i guess the maximum would be 100 but once the slider passes 100 it continues the in the circle to 101, 102..200, 201, 202, etc.

Any ideas?

Comment: it will be always limited by `Integer.MAX_INT`

Comment: @Blackbelt Sir , How fast you are .

Comment: Ok, any ideas of a different control that can accomplish this?  Maybe progressbar?